# Unable to fetch the available data with the request params id in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a following get request on the server:

```js
payments.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Payment.findAll({
        where: {
            requestID: req.params.id
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        res.status(200).json({status: "Ok", res})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(404).json({status: false});
        // res.send(err);
    })
})
```

When I test to get all the payment details from the given request params id in postman then I failed to fetch the available data from the database and it always runs to the catch() function as shown in the figure below:

[image: Get Request with the request id params passed]

When I hit the Send button in postman, my nodejs console will execute the following query function:

[image: Executed Queries in Sequelize]

When I tested this query in the XAMPP Server, then it shows the data.

```sql
SELECT `payment_id`, `stud_uuid` AS `studID`, `request_id` AS `requestID`, `request_date` AS `requestDate`, `amount`, `ins_uuid` AS `insID`, `status` FROM `tbl_payment` AS `tbl_payment` WHERE `tbl_payment`.`request_id` = 'd690ae99-c6bf-4568-ad2b-980bfb4696e8'
```

The data is as follows:

[image: Response from the executed query]

What I am missing in the nodejs function that I am unable to show the available data??
Why my get request is always going to the catch() statement..
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: clearly `Payment.findAll` is failing with an error `err` - do you know what the error is? hint: `err` will contain meaningful data to help you solve your problem

Comment: @JaromandaX There is no error thrown. The query is executed with empty json.

Comment: *it always goes to catch* ... sounds like an error to me ... what is the value of `err` - use that to help you debug

Comment: My guess is that `findAll` is doing strict equality, and you're passing in a string where it expects a number.

Comment: @proselenos - You said *"...it always runs to the catch() function..."* That's an error. `err` will contain information about what the problem was.

Comment: thing is, with promises `.catch` basically will catch errors so they won't be thrown :p

Comment: So how do I see the error logged into the console @JaromandaX ?

Comment: huh? console.log usually will log to the console - but you don't console.log at the moment ... you could also `res.status(404).json({status: false, err});` to send the error back in the response

Comment: you could add a “console.log(‘error’, err) to your catch function

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When I test the route in postman passing the request ID then in the console a sequelize query is shown but no error.

Comment: also... a little offtopic - if its a /:id endpoint, shouldn’t you call a Payments.findOne instead of findAll? since ID are unique and such...

Comment: res.status(404).json({status: false, err});
This is what I receive: err is empty.
{
    "status": false,
    "err": {}
}

Comment: @FelipeSkinner When I do findOne also it shows the same problem.

Comment: TypeError: res.status is not a function when I add console.log(err) to the catch function.

Comment: you should probably console.log(res) to check what is in there

Comment: well, whatever `Payment.findAll` is, it's not very helpful regarding errors - is that function your code? or is it part of some library?

Comment: It's my own code @JaromandaX Payment is a model. ANd findAll is a sequelize function

Comment: so, you wrote findAll function? you need to reject meaningful errors if you did

Comment: @proselenos - That error message lead me to the problem. The problem is that you've used the name `res` for the result of the promise: `.then(res =>` That shadows the `res` you received in the `get` callback. Rename it: `.then(result => { res.status(200).json({status: "Ok", res: result})`.

Comment: Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future. @proselenos - Probably best to delete the question, since it's quite specific to your situation. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. Your last comment was the time saver. I got the response, after I changed the name res for the result of the promise as you told.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You can post it as an answer. It helped me.

Comment: ```json

{
    "status": "Ok",
    "res": {
        "payment_id": 2,
        "studID": "771d7def-a638-48a1-a739-e911fb6c5ccd",
        "requestID": "d690ae99-c6bf-4568-ad2b-980bfb4696e8",
        "requestDate": "2020-03-07",
        "amount": 2000,
        "insID": "035f93a5-2f92-4cc1-9668-3103da7ce5e8",
        "status": true
    }
}
```

Comment: @proselenos - Sure, if you like. :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
payments.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Payment.findAll({
        where: {
            requestID: req.params.id
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
// −−−−−−−^^^
        res.status(200).json({status: "Ok", res})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(404).json({status: false});
        // res.send(err);
    })
})
```

You're shadowing the `res` you received in the `get` callback with the result of the promise. Rename it:

```
payments.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Payment.findAll({
        where: {
            requestID: req.params.id
        }
    })
    .then(result => {
// −−−−−−−^^^^^^
        res.status(200).json({status: "Ok", res: result})
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(404).json({status: false});
        // res.send(err);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is ***res*** being used here promise resolution object of **Payment.findAll**, instead use some other variable so that **res** doesn't get overridden.

```
payments.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    Payment.findAll({
        where: {
            requestID: req.params.id
        }
    })
    .then(**done** => {
        res.status(200).json({status: "Ok", **done**})
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(404).json({status: false});
        // res.send(err);
    })
})
```